# reducing subarrays numbers in Javascript with reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

What I want is to do the same that the following solution, but replacing the whole code with a reduce function. My current code is:

```
function reduce2dArr(cash) {
    let cashList = [];
     cash.forEach(subArr => cashList.unshift(subArr[1]));
    let globalcash = cashList.reduce((a, b) => a + b);  
    return globalcash;
  } 

  reduce2dArr([["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]); //335.41
```

And I have tried this:

```
function reduce2dArr(cash) {
    let globalcash = cash.reduce((subArr1, subArr2) => subArr1[1] + subArr2[1])
    return globalcash;
  } 

  reduce2dArr([["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]); // NaN
```

In the debugger I could see that `reduce` works fine only the first iteration (3.05)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a start value, because you add a part of an array and return a number.

This number is the next value, but this is not an array to take the second element from it.

```js
function reduce2dArr(cash) {
    return cash.reduce((sum, subArray) => sum + subArray[1], 0);
}

console.log(reduce2dArr([["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]));
```

By using an array as accumulator, you need to return an array for taking the second element of both sub arrays.

```js
function reduce2dArr(cash) {
    return cash
        .reduce((subArray1, subArray2) => [null, subArray1[1] + subArray2[1]])
        [1]; // take only the sum
}

console.log(reduce2dArr([["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]));
```